# Bootstrap Carousel not working with angular ng-route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Am creating a simple angularjs application with ng-route, the index.html page have a bootstrap carousel which have next and previous button when click on that button am being navigated to the next Html page below is my plunkr link as well as my script.js file please do corrections if am wrong, I have searched a lot but didn't find a proper solutions for this issue

[Working Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/VUS8RjQkVQabEBxRWMdB?p=preview)

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
appname.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'indexView.html',
            controller: 'indexController'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html', 
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'contact.html', 
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }]).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isIndexPage = function() {
      return $location.path() === '/';
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Jaanus When I click the bootstrap carousel next or previous button it navigate to the next page but it should take me to te ext image not the next page, you can check it on the plunkr link provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, everything works nicely now.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JcInw9ZUz6vfFO5InV7N?p=preview

Rewrote the `MainCtrl` part, before the `MainCtrl` was created once and never updated, but now it listens to route change and hides the carousel accordingly.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
  $scope.isIndexPage = $location.path() === '/';
});
```

Comment: but I don't need the carousel in all pages, only in home page is enough, I think now you got me